# What is solution for this error "Unable to create a XML-RPC client"?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, xml-rpc, testlink

What configuration follow for "Integration of selenium with Testlink 1.9.9"?

I want exact working step for configure "Selenium" with "Testlink" in Ubuntu12.04 LTS (Linux or Ubuntu).

I am tried with steps which are given for "Windows OS".

**Working :**
1) Testlink working properly
2) Apache working properly
3) Php5 working properly

$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE; is added

**Used URL :**
  -URL = /var/www/html/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php

**When I have run my code I face this error:**

-testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException: Unable to create a XML-RPC client.

Comment: $tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE; added in file already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path "http://localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php" remains same for Ubuntu as well as Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have made change in path : "http://localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php"

It work correctly.
Thank You