# Can someone please explain me what could be the solution for this error “Unable to create a XML-RPC client”?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xml-rpc, testlink

I was on integrating testlink (version 1.9.20-12) with the selenium webdriver by using this blog https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/testlink-tutorial-3/

I have done all the preequisites and all the steps. But I am getting this error **"Unable to create a XML-RPC client"**. I have also came to know that my API is not getting connected as isConnected method from TestlinkApiClient is giving me false value.

I have gone and check the solutions given on [What is solution for this error "Unable to create a XML-RPC client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272881/what-is-solution-for-this-error-unable-to-create-a-xml-rpc-client) and [TestLink XML-RPC The call to the xml-rpc client failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785816/testlink-xml-rpc-the-call-to-the-xml-rpc-client-failed) but still my error was not resolved.

here is the code snippet.

```
TestLinkAPIClient tlApi = new TestLinkAPIClient(URL, DEVKEY);

boolean value = tlApi.isConnected;

System.out.println("API Connected : " + value);

tlApi.reportTestCaseResult(testProject, testPlan, testCase, build, notes, result);
```

providing DEVKEY from Testlink from user profile and URL as "http://127.0.0.1:81/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php"

Can someone explain what caused this error and how to fix it.

Comment: Add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Dont have any stacktrace or console errors.  Message kept coming as **"Unable to create a XML-RPC client"**.

Comment: The code that you have shown us will not print that message.  Show us the code that is printing that message.

Comment: result = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;//set test execution status as passed in testlink
notes = ("Status updated. Executed successfully on TestProject. Report URL : " + executionReport);
Thread.sleep(15000);
TestLinkAPIClient tlApi = new TestLinkAPIClient(URL, DEVKEY);
System.out.println("URL : " +  URL);
boolean value = tlApi.isConnected;
System.out.println("API Connected : " + value);
Thread.sleep(10000);
tlApi.reportTestCaseResult(testProject, testPlan, testCase, build, notes, result);
Thread.sleep(15000);

Comment: 1.) Put it into the Question.  Use the EDIT button.  (Do you seriously expect people to read >>that<< to help you?) 2) Please explain which line of that code outputs the message.

Comment: I have already added the code snippet where I am getting this error